# Graph API search for user broken since Q3 2013 migration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if the Graph API search for a user by email address is available since the Q3 2013 migration went into effect on July 10, 2013?

I know that searching for applications was removed, and the notes say that an application access token is now required for search other than Places and Pages, but I can't seem to get search to work for type=user at all anymore.

I used to be able to just fetch data from a url similar to:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=email_address&type=user&access_token=valid_user_access_token

Relevant documentation I have found:

- https:// developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/
- https:// developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/
  Especially the following note: 
  "Graph API search changes
  App access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except Places and Pages. Search for application will no longer be supported."

I've tried using the app access_token in the url directly as well as using the PHP SDK, but I always get the following exception back:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

Is this just not possible to do anymore, or am I missing something (it seems like the docs are out of date at a minimum).

Thanks!

Comment: So could you please read the error message?

Comment: "it seems like the docs are out of date at a minimum" --- there is a huge text block with red exclamation mark on the documentation page

Comment: I am asserting I have a valid access_token and that the API has a bug and doesn't match, not only the out of date docs, but also the description of what changed in Q3 2013 migration...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dwatermelon%26type%3Dpost -- it works if you have a valid access_token

Comment: Thanks for the link to that tool. I hadn't seen it before. Unfortunately it does NOT work if you use an email address as the value for "q" regardless of access token.  Additionally, it does not work with an app access token contrary to the notes on the Q3 2013 migration. So for example, this works: search?q=jason hills&type=user&access_token= (removed), but search?q=jasonhi@hotmail.com&type=user&access_token= (removed) does not work. I'm really looking for someone from Facebook to respond, as they point people to Stackoverflow for support.

Comment: Makes sense. Put these details into the question

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a fix, I came across a reply on this same "bug report" posted at Facebook and a Facebook developer replied that you cannot search by email anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have a valid access token, facebook is not allowing now to search for public feeds, read here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0

They have removed the search action, and moved it as 'Public Feeds API' which is available to certain partners only.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

You can still get results by directly hitting the URL:

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=[QUERY]&access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%5bQUERY%5d&access_token=%5bACCESS-TOKEN%5d)